# How can I use Simple Injector as a boostrapper in NancyFX?

Tags: nancy, simple-injector

I have seen the following two links
[Nancy FX Discussion](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1227),
[Simple Injector Discussion](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/541398)
However, I really want to use the simple injector.

Is there anyway I can use the simple injector as Bootstrapper in NancyFX(v.1.1)?

Comment: It seems to me the Simple Injector discussion you linked to contains a working bootstrapper using Simple Injector. So just grab that. What am I missing?

Comment: There's a [discussion on the Nancy forum](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1227) between the Nancy and Simple Injector folks, but for some reason, the Nancy folks let the discussion die.

Comment: Also checkout https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/110